# Aquamacs seems to ignore the "~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/customizations.el" file it creates

Tags: aquamacs

Running Aquamacs 3.0a on Mac OS X 10.8.5, I used `customize-faces` to change the background and foreground and to pick a nice font. Aquamacs added the following lines to a file it created called `~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/customizations.el`:

```
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:background "Black" :foreground "White" :height 130 :family "Menlo"))))
 '(mode-line ((t (:background "grey75" :foreground "black" :box nil)))))
```

I also used customize to deactivate autofaces and Aquamacs duly added `'(aquamacs-autoface-mode nil)` to the `custom-set-variables` form in the same file.

Upon restarting Aquamacs these customizations aren't in effect. Instead it decides to give me black background and foreground --black is a fine color, but using it for both foreground and background is clearly too much of a good thing.

Running `M-x load-file "~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/customizations.el"`, as I expected, applies my settings. I currently put the following function definition in my `~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences.el`:

```
(defun fix-aquamacs ()
  (interactive)
  (load-file "~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/customizations.el"))
```

and manually run `M-x fix-aquamacs` every time I have to restart it (which is not often). Does anyone know what is happening? My guesses:

1. Aquamacs puts stuff in customizations.el but doesn't load it! (This is clearly wrong, I can't believe Aquamacs would do that.)
2. Something else is changing the fonts after Aquamacs loads `customizations.el`, but what? My `Preferences.el` does not contain anything related to faces, I don't have a `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`. Is there some other file Aquamacs loads at startup? Does it also get ideas about fonts and colors from some Mac OS X system settings? (I am clueless about Mac OS X, I only use Macs ocasionally.)

Comment: What version of OSX? Are you running as an administrative user?

Comment: Oh, right, it's OS X 10.8.5, Aquamacs is version 3.0a and I am not an administrative user nor could I gain access to administrative powers, @CanadianLuke.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include that information. Thanks, and hopefully someone can help with it